# Объяснение текста задания C#

Tags: c#

1. Создайте абстрактный класс MessageSerializerBase.
2. Класс будет содержать конструктор, который получает объект типа IEncryption, который затем будет сохранен в свойстве с именем Encryption.
3. Создайте обобщенный класс MessageSerializer, который будет наследоваться от класса MessageSerializerBase. Общий параметр будет ограничен, чтобы разрешать только типы, которые реализуют интерфейс iMessage и имеют открытый непараметрический конструктор.
4. Класс будет содержать метод Deserialize, принимающий текстовую строку и возвращающий объект типа, заданного общим параметром класса. Внутри этого метода создается экземпляр(инстанция) типа, который задается общим параметром класса. Затем проверяется, соответствует ли первый символ переданной текстовой строки значению, возвращаемому методом GetMark для экземпляра объекта(?) **(!)**. Если нет, то генерируется исключение InvalidMessageException. Затем проверяется, соответствует ли второй символ строки значению, возвращаемому методом GetMark для объекта в свойстве шифрования.

Собственно, из задания мне абсолютно не понятно что значит строка - "Внутри этого метода создается экземпляр(инстанция) типа, который задается общим параметром класса. Затем проверяется, соответствует ли первый символ переданной текстовой строки значению, возвращаемому методом GetMark для экземпляра объекта(?) **(!)**"

Что за экземпляр типа, что надо создать? Мне абсолютно не ясно, может быть есть человек, который достаточно разбирается в C# и может объяснить это?

Код, который я сделал по этому заданию:

```
    public class MessageSerializer<T> where T: MessageSerializerBase, IMessage
    {
        IEncryption Encryption;
        public MessageSerializer(IEncryption value)
        {
            Encryption = value;
        }

        public string Serialize(T obj) // не важно, часть другого задания.
        {
            string temp  = Encryption.Encrypt( Serialize(obj));
            return $"{obj.GetMark()}{Encryption.GetMark()}{temp}";
        } 
        public T Deserialize(string any)
        {

            if (Encryption.GetMark() == any[0])// Не ясно что тут нужно. Сравнение с инстанцией(какой?)
            {
                
            }

            if (Encryption.GetMark() == any[1])
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Интерфейс выглядит так:

```
    public interface IMessage
    {
        public string Serialize();
        public void Deserialize(string anything);
        public char GetMark();
    }
```

MessageSerializerBase просто пустой абстрактный

Comment: Создать экземпляр это `new ИмяТипа()`

Comment: @aepot можно, если не сложно, строчку с кодом всего этого? А то я не могу найти правильный формат для создания этого объекта. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: @aepot это было бы то, что требуется?             var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте прочитаю задание по слогам

```
public interface IEncryption
{
    public char GetMark();
}

//Создайте абстрактный класс MessageSerializerBase.
public abstract class MessageSerializerBase
{
    public IEncryption Encryption { get; }
    //Класс будет содержать конструктор, который получает объект типа IEncryption
    public MessageSerializerBase(IEncryption encryption)
    {
        //который затем будет сохранен в свойстве с именем Encryption.
        Encryption = encryption;
    }
}

public interface IMessage
{
    public char GetMark();
}

//Создайте обобщенный класс MessageSerializer
public class MessageSerializer<T>
    //который будет наследоваться от класса MessageSerializerBase
    : MessageSerializerBase
    //Общий параметр будет ограничен, чтобы разрешать только типы, которые реализуют интерфейс IMessage
    where T : IMessage,
    //и имеют открытый непараметрический конструктор.
    new()
{
    public MessageSerializer(IEncryption encryption) : base(encryption)
    {
    }

    //Класс будет содержать метод Deserialize, принимающий текстовую строку и возвращающий объект типа, заданного общим параметром класса.
    public T Deserialize(string text)
    {
        //Внутри этого метода создается экземпляр(инстанция) типа, который задается общим параметром класса
        T instance = new T();
        //Затем проверяется, соответствует ли первый символ переданной текстовой строки значению, возвращаемому методом GetMark для экземпляра объекта.
        if (text[0] != instance.GetMark())
        {
            //Если нет, то генерируется исключение InvalidMessageException.
            throw new InvalidMessageException();
        }
        //Затем проверяется, соответствует ли второй символ строки значению, возвращаемому методом GetMark для объекта в свойстве шифрования.
        if (text[1] != Encryption.GetMark())
        {

        }
        return instance;
    }
}

public class InvalidMessageException : Exception
{
}
```